# In Silverlight how do I set a buttons enabled state to be enabled based on items selected in a listbox?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, mvvm

I have a dialog that contains a listbox and the customary ok, cancel buttons. I would like set the enabled state of the ok button to be enabled only if an item in the listbox has been select. I would like to do this with bindings rather than in the code behind.

I may have been going down the wrong route but I have being trying to do something like the following

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProjectList, Path=??? }"
```

As you can probably see I have no idea what would go in the "Path"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ProjectList` is the name of the list box then you should be able to use `SelectedItem`.

You will need to bind through a converter that checks for the `SelectedItem` being null and returning false in that case.

So your XAML becomes:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProjectList, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemToBool}}"
```

and the selector looks something like this:

```
public class SelectedItemToBool : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent just what I wanted. Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm new to XAML/Silverlight and this is one of those little things that make the platform so easy to work with.
Thanks for the tip!